# What's the problem in this code for finding whether a number is prime?

Tags: python, primes

Whenever I executed the code I get wrong answers only. I try for 2 numbers 55 and 89 and I get same answer for both no matter how I alter the code.
I know it's a dumb question but I tried a lot of ways but it doesn't work. I guess it's some kind of indentation problem. For me it's a bit hard to get into python because of no use of brackets so please help this noob. Thank you

```
a=int(input("Enter the number you want to check for prime: \n"))
b = False
for i in (2,a):
    if(a%i)==0:
        b = True
        break
    i=i+1
if b:
    print("The number is not a prime number")
else:
    print("The number is a prime number")
```

Comment: Please add the error you are getting, it will be easier for people to help you that way.

Comment: I suspect the problem is in `for i in (2,a)`. `i` will be either `2` or the value of `a` in that loop. Since `a` is divisible by itself, `b` will always be `True`.

Comment: @rickdenhaan nice got it. So I've to replace (2,a) with range(2,a)

Comment: Yes. Keep in mind that this method will start to get _very_ slow on larger numbers. Having the range stop at `floor(a/2)` would speed things up then because obviously `101` is not divisible by anything above 50 (51x2=102) so there’s no real point in continuing to check.

Comment: @rickdenhaan There is actually no reason to keep checking over `sqrt(a)`...

Comment: well yes ofc but sqrt works better.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so your error is not a code error. Your algorithm is incorrect.
For any given number you do 2 checks:

- check if it is even (mod 2)
- check if it id divisible by itself

This does not say anything about it being a prime number. This is probably a homework assignment so I will not give you a working solution here, but I think that this should help you on your way.

Ok maybe I see something else:
your loop `for i in (2,a)` and later on `i=i+1` does not do what you think it does.

You can verify this by adding a statement `print(i)` in your code.
And look at the [range](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp) function, this might help you out.

Comment: It's not homework, I'm just trying to learn python but I corrected my code anyways.
Thanks

Comment: edited my answer, cuz I did see where you might have expected a different result from your loop